# A mistake in my HTML code (somewhere?)

Tags: html

I recently paid a coder to create some html code for my website. I have since messed with it (I know, stupid!) and it no longer works.

The image was supposed to hover to a purple image from a grey and now it no longer hovers at all.

---

```
<div align="center">
     <img src="/instagram+purple.png" style="display:none" />
     <a style="display:inline-block"
       onmouseout="$(this).find('img').attr(src="static1.squarespace.com/static/55b94761e4b0d425914723a8/t/…)  
</div>
```

---

```
   onmouseover="$(this).find('img').attr('src','static1.squarespace.com/static/55b94761e4b0d425914723a8/t/…;
   href="instagram.com/thedistancelive"; target="_blank"><img
   src="static1.squarespace.com/static/55b94761e4b0d425914723a8/t/…;
   style="border:none;height:50px; width:50px;">
```

---

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
   a {text-decoration: none; } a{color: #515253;}
   a.ex1:hover, a.ex1:active {color: #5d3984;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p><font color="#515253"><p><div
   style="font-family:blog_script; margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: 0px"><a class="ex1"
   href="default.asp"><font size=" 5.5">@Thedistancelive</font></p>
 </a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: div align="center">
<img src="/instagram+purple.png" style="display:none" />
  <a style="display:inline-block" onmouseout="$(this).find('img').attr(src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55b94761e4b0d425914723a8/t/579927df8419c2e66a52db8c/1469655007841/instagrey.png')

Comment: onmouseover="$(this).find('img').attr('src','http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55b94761e4b0d425914723a8/t/57aa774ecd0f68ea5c95c4b4/1470789461311/instagram+purple.png)" href="http://www.instagram.com/thedistancelive" target="_blank"><img  src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55b94761e4b0d425914723a8/t/579927df8419c2e66a52db8c/1469655007841/instagrey.png" style="border:none;height:50px; width:50px;">

Comment: <html>
<head>
<style>a {text-decoration: none; } a{color: #515253;}

a.ex1:hover, a.ex1:active {color: #5d3984;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><font color="#515253"><p><div style="font-family:blog_script; margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: 0px"><a class="ex1" href="default.asp"><font size=" 5.5">@Thedistancelive</font></p>
</a> 

</body>
</html>

Comment: Edited the code somewhat for you. If you did not succeed: (1) `edit`, (2) paste (3) select pasted text (4) press `{}` which indents the text by 4 spaces which marks the text as code to be displayed as-is.